# Complex collections with Automapper

Tags: automapper

Here is what I have where I hope someone can help us out:

```
class Source
{  
    string name { get; set; }
    Inner { get; set; }
}

class Inner
{
    Col A { get; set; }
    Col B { get; set; }
}


class Col : IList<ClassX>, IEnunmerable<ClassX>
```

I need to map class `Source` to a destination type which has:

```
class Dest  
{  
    string name { get; set; }  
    IList<ClassY> A { get; set;}  
    IList<ClassY> B { get; set;}  
}
```

Now, `ClassX` and class `ClassY` share the same properties. `ClassY` class has a subset of the `ClassX` primitive properties with the exact same names and types.

Tried all kinds of mappings. Just the `ClassX` to `ClassY` map, with the collections, without and with any mapping get no mapping found between or missing configuration between `Source` and `Dest`

AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<`Source`, `Dest`>(src);

Can someone help me out with the mapping? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify: you want dest.name to come from source.name and dest.A to come from source.Inner.A and dest.B to come from source.Inner.B?

Comment: Patrick, yes that's the behavior I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a few months old, but if you're still looking for an answer, this is what I tried that worked:

```
class Source
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Inner Inner { get; set; }
}
class Inner
{
    public Col A { get; set; }
    public Col B { get; set; }
}
class Col : List<ClassX> { }
class ClassX
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ClassX() : this(0, "") { }
    public ClassX(int index, string name)
    {
        this.Index = index;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
class ClassY
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ClassY() : this(0, "") { }
    public ClassY(int index, string name)
    {
        this.Index = index;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
class Dest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ClassY> A { get; set; }
    public List<ClassY> B { get; set; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void ComplexTest()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.A, config => config.MapFrom(src => src.Inner.A))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.B, config => config.MapFrom(src => src.Inner.B));
    Mapper.CreateMap<ClassX, ClassY>();

    Source source = new Source
        {
            Name = "Source",
            Inner = new Inner
                {
                    A = new Col
                        {
                            new ClassX(1, "First"),
                            new ClassX(2, "Second"),
                            new ClassX(3, "Third"),
                            new ClassX(4, "Fourth"),
                        },
                    B = new Col
                        {
                            new ClassX(5, "Fifth"),
                            new ClassX(6, "Sixth"),
                            new ClassX(7, "Seventh"),
                            new ClassX(8, "Eighth"),
                        },
                }
        };

    Dest destination = Mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(source);

    Assert.AreEqual(source.Name, destination.Name);
    Assert.AreEqual(source.Inner.A.Count, destination.A.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual(source.Inner.B.Count, destination.B.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual(source.Inner.A[0].Name, destination.A[0].Name);
    Assert.AreEqual(source.Inner.B[0].Name, destination.B[0].Name);
}
```

I didn't go too in-depth with my Asserts, so there may be something I missed, but they appear to be mapped properly.